# resize based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I have a canvas and some tabs on my page: http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html
Now these are set manual sizes. I am wondering how to make them resize based on the screen size as now they work fine on mine but on smaller screens it is cropped.

I would like the canvas to be 2/3 the width and the tabs to be 1/3 and the height to be the whole screen height. Is this possible and what would be the best way to do this? CSS, divs? jquery? I know how to make canvas the entire size of the screen with some jquery but I am not sure this is the right way so I came here to ask! thanks!

Comment: You could use percentages in CSS with @media-queries.

Comment: I have no experience with css, could you explain how and where to do this?

Comment: I don't think you need media queries for this. You'd do the canvas at 66.6666666% and tabs container at 33.3333333%. You'd have to rerender the canvas on window resize though since the width could change and cut off some of what was produced.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux That's a bit overkill. `33%` and `67%` will do fine.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat, I prefer precision.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("#canvas").css('width', 70 + '%');
$("#canvas").css('height', 100 + '%');
$("#toolbox").css('width', 30 + '%');
$("#toolbox").css('height', 100 + '%');
```

copy it into the initialize function of your javascript code, if you think it is necessary you can add a 'resize' event handler for the window

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#canvas").css('width', 70 + '%');
    $("#canvas").css('height', 100 + '%');
    $("#toolbox").css('width', 30 + '%');
    $("#toolbox").css('height', 100 + '%');
});
```

where '#canvas' and '#toolbox' are the ids of your canvas and toolbox/pane respectively.

I hope it helps.